# Define WPF Fill in class

Tags: c#

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        RRefresh.Fill { get; set; } // Does not work
        private SolidColorBrush RRefresh.Fill { get; set; } // Does not work

    public void RRefresh_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickCount++;
        RRefresh.Fill = (ClickCount % 2 == 1) ? CustomGreen : CustomRed;
    }

    public void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Driver != null && ((SolidColorBrush)RRefresh.Fill).Color == CustomGreen.Color)
            // Trying to acces RRefresh.Fill in this check
```

How can I define `RRefresh.Fill` in my class so I can use it in different methods since `RRefresh.Fill { get; set; }` won't work

Comment: Can you show how you tried to define Fill in your RRefresh class?

Comment: I have updated the code @PicMickael

Comment: What is RRefresh? Is it a custom class you created? the name of a control?

Comment: Its a rectangle that can be toggled @PicMickael

Comment: So if I understand well, you defined a rectangle and you are trying to dynamically change its fill color?

Comment: I can change its color to either CustomGreen or CustomRed, I want the current color to be accessible in all methods so I can check against it in my last method

Answer (score 0):

So you are creating a WPF rectangle and want to be able to read and write its color from the code behind.

```
<Rectangle Width="480" Height="200" Fill="{Binding Path=FillColor}"/>
```

You will need to extend your class with INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public Brush FillColor  
{   
  get { return this.fillColor; }   
  set
  {
     this.fillColor = value;
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
       PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }   
  }
}
```

after that you can access the color directly

```
FillColor = (ClickCount % 2 == 1) ? CustomGreen.Color : CustomRed.Color;
```

and

```
if (Driver != null && FillColor == CustomGreen.Color)
{
// do something here
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with `INotifyPropertyChanged`? I have never used that, where do I put it in my code

Comment: I have no class for my rectangle/colors, there's no way to define it in my Main window class?